# Converting primitive data type to void pointer type

Tags: c++, c, pointers, pthreads

I was reading about pthreads [here](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). In one example they had given [this](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/samples/hello.c) source code.

While creating a thread, they are passing a long type, type casted as void * type to the function !.

Inside the function they receive this value and reverse cast to get the long value.

Q1: Is it allowed to convert a pointer type to primitive data type and vice-verca (In C and C++)?

Q2. If so, is it a good thing to do this ? Shouldn't they create a pointer to this long type, then type cast this pointer as void * and pass it on to the function.

This idea of conversion of a primitive type to pointer type I am finding very confusing ?
Conversion from any pointer type to void* in understandable, but how come primitive data type be stored in a void* type ? Isnt there a possibility that on a particular system size of a primitive type might be bigger that size allocated for pointer type ?

Comment: On a system that supports pthreads, it is requried to work (POSIX compliance). On systems in general, it might not work.

Comment: you are confusing two things, a pointer and the pointee, the `void*` is a *pointer* just like `long*` (the result of `&longValue`), they should have the same size on most systems AFAIK, the pointee can be any size; the address (pointer) is normally always the same size (try `sizeof(void*)` and `sizeof(long*)` on your system). When you call this function, you pass the *pointer* to your data cast to a `void*`, not the data itself cast to a `void*`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Q1: yes, but it is implementation defined (= platform depending) whether this will work. A version that would be a bit safer would use `uintptr_t` instead of `long`.

Q2: It is definitively bad style. There is not much performance penalty in doing that properly by allocating a `long` and passing the address.

Comment: is it possible to cast pointer to primitive data type by dynamic_cast?

Comment: So, does it mean that it is better not to follow this tutorial and many other that I found right now? Will it be ok to write something like: rc = pthread_create(&threads[t], NULL, PrintHello, (void*)&t); ?

Comment: @H-Bahrami dynamic_cast can be applied only on references and pointers.

Comment: on some platforms it is the only way to pass data to a thread e.g. windows and _beginthread so saying it is "bad style" is maybe a bit OTT

Comment: @AndersK, here it is pthreads and the interface demands a `void*` it should always be possible to pass a pointer to the data.